# Minimal Example to use the MKL Linear Equation Solver

Tags: c++, lapack, blas, intel-mkl

I would like to use BLAS for finding the solution of an equation structured `AX = B`, and X is to be solved.

The Matrix A is of shape `m x 4`, B is of the shape `m x 3` and X is of shape `4 x 1`.

My code is as follows -

```
void fitSphere(float* points, float* points_square_negative,  int m){

    // Sphere Params = a, b, c, r;
    // points x Solution = points_square_negative
    
    int n = 4;
    int ipiv;
    int info;
    int nrhs = 3;

    sgetrf(&m, &n, points, &m, &ipiv, &info);
    
    printf("%d \n", info);

    sgetrs("N", &m, &nrhs, points, &m, &ipiv, points_square_negative ,&nrhs, &info);

    printf("%d \n", info);

    printf("%f %f %f %f \n", points_square_negative[0], points_square_negative[1], points_square_negative[2], points_square_negative[3]);    
}
```

However I run into a segmentation fault at `sgetrs`, and I am not sure why.

It would be great if someone could post a minimal example for solving `AX=B` using BLAS where A is any general matrix, and could also highlight the meaning of parameters, namely the `lda` and `nrhs`, I did go through the documentation but did not find it informative ..

TIA

Comment: Matrix dimensions seem to be incorrect. The product of AX has mx1 shape.

Comment: Oh my bad, It is a typo, Matrix B is `mx1`. I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

Below are the corresponding meaning for paramenters been mentioned.

nrhs ->
The number of right-hand sides;

lda ->
The leading dimension of a;

Not all “BLAS” routines are actually in BLAS; some are LAPACK extensions that functionally fit in the BLAS.

Regarding the getrs paramenters and funtionality description, you could refer to below link.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/lapack-routines/lapack-linear-equation-routines/lapack-linear-equation-computational-routines/solve-sys-of-linear-equations-lapack-computation/getrs.html

Could you please make sure the paramenters you enter are valid so that code runs fine.

In addition, you could refer to examples under below path depending in your functionality requirement.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl(Your oneAPI version)\examples\examples_core_c.zip\c